# please specify typings for following case

Tags: typescript

```
var zooKeeper = function()
{
    this.status="initialising";
}

zooKeeper.prototype = {
    getCountryByName:function(name) {
        return name;
    },
    getCountryByCode:function(code)
    {
        return code;
    }

}
```

The above code is sample of already written large javascript code. I copied code to a ***.ts*** file and writing **.d.ts** file so that i can get intellisense,type information etc in **VSCODE**.

Most of the code contains a variable which acts as a ***function*** and has ***prototype*** object with some functions ,as above ***zooKeeper*** is assigned a ***function*** and ***zooKeeper.prototype*** contains some more functions.

How to write typings in .d.ts file for the above case. However I write Iam not able to satisfy compiler?

I have tried this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
declare var zooKeeper: () => IZookeeper;
export interface IZookeeper {
    getCountryByName: (name: string) => string;
    getCountryByCode: (code: string) => string;
}
```

Keep in mind that your `.d.ts` file should have no implementations at all. It is strictly interface definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare call signatures right on an interface:

`interface ZooKeeper {
    (): void;
    getCountryByName(name: string): string;
    getCountryByCode(code: string): string;
}`